# Filtering array's object and returning parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 arrays:

Array 1 called **Ingredients** containing a list of string values:

```
Ingredients = [
  "vodka",
  "orange juice",
  "lemon juice",
  "pineapple juice",
  "apple juice",
  "lime juice",
  "gin",
  "whiskey",
  "rum",
  "triple sec",
]
```

Array 2 called **Cocktails** containing a list of objects each having an **ingredients** field with some values:

```
Cocktails:  Array [
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1101", 
    "ingredients": " gin, lime syrup, lime",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1102", 
    "ingredients": "vodka, orange juice",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1103", 
    "ingredients": "rum, coke",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1104", 
    "ingredients": "sweet vermouth, campari, prosecco",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1105", 
    "ingredients": "Gin, Olive Juice, Olives, Dry vermouth",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1106", 
    "ingredients": " Vodka, Triple Sec, Lime Juice",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1107", 
    "ingredients": " vodka, Raspberry Liqueur, Pineapple Juice",
}
]
```

I am looping through all objects from **Cocktails** and returning only the ones that have ONLY 1 missing ingredient (value) from the **Ingredients** array. I'm also saving the missing ingredient suing the following function.

```
const cocktailPartialMatch = Cocktails.filter(function (item) {     
      var itemIngredient = item.ingredients.toLowerCase().split(",");
      var matchCount = 0;
      var missingIngredient = [];

      itemIngredient.forEach((element) =>
        Ingredients.indexOf(element.trim()) >= 0
          ? matchCount++
          : missingIngredient.push(element)
      );
      // return item if there is only 1 missing ingredient
      return itemIngredient.length - matchCount == 1;
      
    });
```

All working as expected except that I also want to save the missing ingredient.

The result of this function is a filtered list of the original Cocktails array.
My objective is to obtain a new array with both the filtered cocktail object and its missing ingredient, something like...

```
cocktailPartialMatch = [{object} {missingIngredient}, {object} {missingIngredient}...]

I'm correctly fetching missingIngredient[] but failing to understand how to return it for each object.
```

Comment: do you have a complete result of the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and get new objects with an array of missing items.

```js
const
    ingredients = ["vodka", "orange juice", "lemon juice", "pineapple juice", "apple juice", "lime juice", "gin", "whiskey", "rum", "triple sec"],
    cocktails = [{ alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1101", ingredients: " gin, lime syrup, lime" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1102", ingredients: "vodka, orange juice" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1103", ingredients: "rum, coke" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1104", ingredients: "sweet vermouth, campari, prosecco" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1105", ingredients: "Gin, Olive Juice, Olives, Dry vermouth" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1106", ingredients: " Vodka, Triple Sec, Lime Juice" }, { alcoholic: true, drinkId: "1107", ingredients: " vodka, Raspberry Liqueur, Pineapple Juice" }],
    cocktailPartialMatch = cocktails.flatMap(item => {
        const
            missingIngredient = item.ingredients
                .toLowerCase()
                .split(",")
                .map(s => s.trim())
                .filter((element) => !ingredients.includes(element));

        return missingIngredient.length <= 1
            ? { ...item, missingIngredient }
            : []
    });

console.log(cocktailPartialMatch);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solutions is perfect for what I'm looking for as I don't even have to change my rendering code since `missingIngredient ` is included inside the same Object. I just changed `missingIngredient.length <= 1 ` to `missingIngredient.length == 1` as I only need the cocktails that have 1 missing ingredient. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

> cocktailPartialMatch = [{object} {missingIngredient}, {object} {missingIngredient}...]

You have to store the two objects in a nested array like this:

> cocktailPartialMatch = [[{object} {missingIngredient}], [{object} {missingIngredient}]...]

Try this code:

```
filtered = [];

for (c of cocktails) {
    missingIngredients = [];    
    
    c.ingredients.split(',').forEach(ingredient => {
        ingredients.map(i => i.trim().toLowerCase());
        if (!ingredients.includes(ingredient.trim().toLowerCase())) {
            missingIngredients.push(ingredient);
        }
    });
    
    if (missingIngredients.length === 1) {
        entry = [c, missingIngredients[0]];
        filtered.push(entry);
    }
}
```

```js
const ingredients = [
  "vodka",
  "orange juice",
  "lemon juice",
  "pineapple juice",
  "apple juice",
  "lime juice",
  "gin",
  "whiskey",
  "rum",
  "triple sec",
]

const cocktails = [
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1101", 
        "ingredients": " gin, lime syrup, lime",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1102", 
        "ingredients": "vodka, orange juice",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1103", 
        "ingredients": "rum, coke",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1104", 
        "ingredients": "sweet vermouth, campari, prosecco",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1105", 
        "ingredients": "Gin, Olive Juice, Olives, Dry vermouth",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1106", 
        "ingredients": " Vodka, Triple Sec, Lime Juice",
    },
    {
        "alcoholic": "true",    
        "drinkId": "1107", 
        "ingredients": " vodka, Raspberry Liqueur, Pineapple Juice",
    }
]


filtered = [];

for (c of cocktails) {
    missingIngredients = [];    
    
    c.ingredients.split(',').forEach(ingredient => {
        ingredients.map(i => i.trim().toLowerCase());
        if (!ingredients.includes(ingredient.trim().toLowerCase())) {
            missingIngredients.push(ingredient);
        }
    });
    
    if (missingIngredients.length === 1) {
        entry = [c, missingIngredients[0]];
        filtered.push(entry);
    }
    
}

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: almost there...I'm getting the following output format `cocktailPartialMatch = [[{object} missingIngredient], [{object} missingIngredient]...]` with  missingIngredient as "Raspberry Liqueur". My idea was getting the 2 objects and accessing it via the index [0] and [1]

Comment: you can access them like this:`cocktailPartialMatch[0][0]` and `cocktailPartialMatch[0][1]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting `cocktailPartialMatch` to use a utility function that instead returns an array of the missing ingredients, then return the filtered array of cocktails and missing ingredients arrays using reduce.

```
const cocktailPartialMatch = Cocktails.reduce((cocktails, cocktail) => {
  const missingIngredients = cocktail.ingredients
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(",")
  .filter((ingredient) => !Ingredients.includes(ingredient));

  if (missingIngredients.length === 1)
    cocktails.push([cocktail, missingIngredients]);

  return cocktails;
}, []);
```

```js
const Ingredients = [
  "vodka",
  "orange juice",
  "lemon juice",
  "pineapple juice",
  "apple juice",
  "lime juice",
  "gin",
  "whiskey",
  "rum",
  "triple sec"
];

const Cocktails = [
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1101",
    ingredients: "gin,lime syrup,lime"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1102",
    ingredients: "vodka,orange juice"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1103",
    ingredients: "rum,coke"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1104",
    ingredients: "sweet vermouth,campari,prosecco"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1105",
    ingredients: "Gin,Olive Juice,Olives,Dry vermouth"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1106",
    ingredients: "Vodka,Triple Sec,Lime Juice"
  },
  {
    alcoholic: "true",
    drinkId: "1107",
    ingredients: "vodka,Raspberry Liqueur,Pineapple Juice"
  }
];

const cocktailPartialMatch = Cocktails.reduce((cocktails, cocktail) => {
  const missingIngredients = cocktail.ingredients
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(",")
  .filter((ingredient) => !Ingredients.includes(ingredient));

  if (missingIngredients.length === 1)
    cocktails.push([cocktail, missingIngredients]);

  return cocktails;
}, []);

console.log(cocktailPartialMatch)
```